# unique identity element

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Consider the set $\{e^{i\alpha} : \alpha \in \mathbb R\}$, which forms a group under multiplication of complex numbers. In P8 of *Steeb, Tanski & Hardy, Problems and solucions for groups, Lie groups, Lie algebras with applications*, it is said that the neutral element is given by $\alpha = 0$, $e^{i 0}=1$. I'm thinking that it could have also said  that the neutral element is given by $\alpha = 2 \pi$ (or $2\pi k$, actually), $e^{2\pi i}=1$. I understand that as complex numbers $e^{i0}$ and $e^{2\pi i}$ point to the same number but, as elements of the group, wouldn't they be different elements? Would that mean that there are infinite neutral elements in this group or in contrast that the $\{e^{i\alpha} : \alpha \in \mathbb R\}$ and $\{e^{i\alpha} : \alpha \in [0,2\pi)\}$ form the same group?

Comment: In the set $\{e^{i\alpha} : \alpha \in \mathbb R\}$ you have $e^{i0}=e^{i2\pi}=1$ being the same element of the set and so the same element of the group.  $\{e^{i\alpha} : \alpha \in \mathbb R\}$ and $\{e^{i\alpha} : \alpha \in [0,2\pi)\}$ are the same set

Comment: Wouldn't then be redundant to define the group as $\{e^{i \alpha} : \alpha \in\mathbb R\}$ (it would be more precise to write it as $\{e^{i \alpha} : \alpha \in [0,2\pi)\}$), isn't it?

Comment: They are both correct: you can write whichever is more convenient in the circumstances.  Writing $\{z:z \in \mathbb C, |z|=1\}$ is an another possibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set can be rewritten :
$$G = \{e^{i\alpha}: \alpha \in\mathbb R\} = \{ z\in \mathbb C |\exists \alpha \in \mathbb R, z= e^{i\alpha}\}$$

Then, it is clear that since $e^{2i\pi k} = e^{i0}$, they are the same element of the group.

Also, using properties of the complex numbers, we can prove that :
$$G = \{ e^{i\alpha}: \alpha\in[0,2\pi)\} = \{z\in\mathbb C| \bar z z = 1\}$$
Those sets are equal.

Comment: This answer says little more than is in Henry's comment [4 minutes earlier]